# How to install tensorflow in 64-bit Windows 10?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, h5py

I have Python version 3.7 64-bit in Windows 10 (64-bit). I tried installing both tensorflow and keras but I end up with the following error all the time:

```
Collecting tensorflow
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f7/08/25e47a53692c2e0dcd2211a493ddfe9007a5cd92e175d6dffa6169a0b392/tensorflow-1.14.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (68.3MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 68.3MB 109kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<2.0,>=1.14.5 in c:\users\naseef\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.16.4)
Collecting keras-preprocessing>=1.0.5 (from tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/28/6a/8c1f62c37212d9fc441a7e26736df51ce6f0e38455816445471f10da4f0a/Keras_Preprocessing-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting astor>=0.6.0 (from tensorflow)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d1/4f/950dfae467b384fc96bc6469de25d832534f6b4441033c39f914efd13418/astor-0.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting tensorflow-estimator<1.15.0rc0,>=1.14.0rc0 (from tensorflow)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3c/d5/21860a5b11caf0678fbc8319341b0ae21a07156911132e0e71bffed0510d/tensorflow_estimator-1.14.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (488kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 491kB 133kB/s
Collecting gast>=0.2.0 (from tensorflow)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4e/35/11749bf99b2d4e3cceb4d55ca22590b0d7c2c62b9de38ac4a4a7f4687421/gast-0.2.2.tar.gz
Collecting keras-applications>=1.0.6 (from tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/71/e3/19762fdfc62877ae9102edf6342d71b28fbfd9dea3d2f96a882ce099b03f/Keras_Applications-1.0.8-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting protobuf>=3.6.1 (from tensorflow)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/46/8b/5e77963dac4a944a0c6b198c004fac4c85d7adc54221c288fc6ca9078072/protobuf-3.9.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (1.0MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.0MB 123kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in c:\users\naseef\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.12.0)
Collecting absl-py>=0.7.0 (from tensorflow)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3c/0d/7cbf64cac3f93617a2b6b079c0182e4a83a3e7a8964d3b0cc3d9758ba002/absl-py-0.8.0.tar.gz (102kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 112kB 2.2MB/s
Collecting wheel>=0.26 (from tensorflow)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/00/83/b4a77d044e78ad1a45610eb88f745be2fd2c6d658f9798a15e384b7d57c9/wheel-0.33.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: wrapt>=1.11.1 in c:\users\naseef\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.11.1)
Collecting termcolor>=1.1.0 (from tensorflow)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8a/48/a76be51647d0eb9f10e2a4511bf3ffb8cc1e6b14e9e4fab46173aa79f981/termcolor-1.1.0.tar.gz
Collecting grpcio>=1.8.6 (from tensorflow)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/32/e7/478737fd426798caad32a2abb7cc63ddb4c12908d9e03471dd3c41992b05/grpcio-1.23.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (1.6MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.6MB 114kB/s
Collecting tensorboard<1.15.0,>=1.14.0 (from tensorflow)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/91/2d/2ed263449a078cd9c8a9ba50ebd50123adf1f8cfbea1492f9084169b89d9/tensorboard-1.14.0-py3-none-any.whl (3.1MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 3.2MB 117kB/s
Collecting google-pasta>=0.1.6 (from tensorflow)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d0/33/376510eb8d6246f3c30545f416b2263eee461e40940c2a4413c711bdf62d/google_pasta-0.1.7-py3-none-any.whl (52kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 61kB ...
Collecting h5py (from keras-applications>=1.0.6->tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5f/97/a58afbcf40e8abecededd9512978b4e4915374e5b80049af082f49cebe9a/h5py-2.10.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\naseef\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from protobuf>=3.6.1->tensorflow) (41.2.0)
Collecting werkzeug>=0.11.15 (from tensorboard<1.15.0,>=1.14.0->tensorflow)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b7/61/c0a1adf9ad80db012ed7191af98fa05faa95fa09eceb71bb6fa8b66e6a43/Werkzeug-0.15.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (328kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 337kB 59kB/s
Collecting markdown>=2.6.8 (from tensorboard<1.15.0,>=1.14.0->tensorflow)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c0/4e/fd492e91abdc2d2fcb70ef453064d980688762079397f779758e055f6575/Markdown-3.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (87kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 137kB/s
Installing collected packages: keras-preprocessing, astor, tensorflow-estimator, gast, h5py, keras-applications, protobuf, absl-py, wheel, termcolor, grpcio, werkzeug, markdown, tensorboard, google-pasta, tensorflow
  Running setup.py install for gast ... done
  Running setup.py install for h5py ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command 'C:\Users\Naseef\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Naseef\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-b3tjfyss\\h5py\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Naseef\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-lnidw34r\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py
    copying h5py\h5py_warnings.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py
    copying h5py\highlevel.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py
    copying h5py\ipy_completer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py
    copying h5py\version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py
    copying h5py\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\_hl
    copying h5py\_hl\attrs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\_hl
    copying h5py\_hl\base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\_hl
    copying h5py\_hl\compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\_hl
    copying h5py\_hl\dataset.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\_hl
    copying h5py\_hl\datatype.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\_hl
    copying h5py\_hl\dims.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\_hl
    copying h5py\_hl\files.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\_hl
    copying h5py\_hl\filters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\_hl
    copying h5py\_hl\group.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\_hl
    copying h5py\_hl\selections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\_hl
    copying h5py\_hl\selections2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\_hl
    copying h5py\_hl\vds.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\_hl
    copying h5py\_hl\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\_hl
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\tests
    copying h5py\tests\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\tests
    copying h5py\tests\test_attribute_create.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\tests
    copying h5py\tests\test_attrs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\tests
    copying h5py\tests\test_attrs_data.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\tests
    copying h5py\tests\test_base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\tests
    copying h5py\tests\test_completions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\tests
    copying h5py\tests\test_dataset.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\tests
    copying h5py\tests\test_dataset_getitem.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\tests
    copying h5py\tests\test_dataset_swmr.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\tests
    copying h5py\tests\test_datatype.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\tests
    copying h5py\tests\test_deprecation.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\tests
    copying h5py\tests\test_dimension_scales.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\tests
    copying h5py\tests\test_dims_dimensionproxy.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\tests
    copying h5py\tests\test_dtype.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\tests
    copying h5py\tests\test_file.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\tests
    copying h5py\tests\test_file2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\tests
    copying h5py\tests\test_file_image.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\tests
    copying h5py\tests\test_filters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\tests
    copying h5py\tests\test_group.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\tests
    copying h5py\tests\test_h5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\tests
    copying h5py\tests\test_h5d_direct_chunk.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\tests
    copying h5py\tests\test_h5f.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\tests
    copying h5py\tests\test_h5p.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\tests
    copying h5py\tests\test_h5pl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\tests
    copying h5py\tests\test_h5t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\tests
    copying h5py\tests\test_objects.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\tests
    copying h5py\tests\test_selections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\tests
    copying h5py\tests\test_slicing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\tests
    copying h5py\tests\test_threads.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\tests
    copying h5py\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\tests
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\tests\test_vds
    copying h5py\tests\test_vds\test_highlevel_vds.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\tests\test_vds
    copying h5py\tests\test_vds\test_lowlevel_vds.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\tests\test_vds
    copying h5py\tests\test_vds\test_virtual_source.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\tests\test_vds
    copying h5py\tests\test_vds\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\h5py\tests\test_vds
    running build_ext
    error: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
    Loading library to get version: hdf5.dll
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'C:\Users\Naseef\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Naseef\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-b3tjfyss\\h5py\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Naseef\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-lnidw34r\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Naseef\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b3tjfyss\h5py\
```

Even installation of h5py using the following command > pu -m pip install h5py did not succeed. Is it a version conflict or should I be installing them from their source?

Comment: i would start over and (to the point of uninstalling python) and use conda to install python and tensorflow into an environment

Comment: Is it because of incompatibility between various packages?

Comment: because packaging and compiling on windows is hard, and conda has it better figured out that pip

Comment: (and you can still use pip if you primarily use conda)

Comment: Thank you, Paul. I have installed it and it works well!